# Please can anyone explain me this recursion code?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int fun(int,int *);
int main()
{
 int x = 5; // variable x and its value is 5
printf("%d,the value of fun is:",fun(5,&x));
return 0;
}
int fun(int n,int *fp)
{
  int t,f;

  if(n <=1)
   {
    *fp = 1;
    return 1;
   }
  t = fun(n-1,fp);
  f = t + *fp;
  *fp = t;
  return (f);
 }
```

I had a test in which this code output was being asked.
Output is 8.But i am not being able to understand the logic of this code.

Comment: Try working through it on paper.  If you know how variables, pointers and function calls work in C, and you have access to paper and something to write with, then you have all the tools you need.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Single-step through it in your debugger and watch the variable values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go through the function line by line.  -- I have ommitted the If condition until the last step for clarity.

```
// Function Call iteration n = 5, fp = 5
int fun(int n,int *fp)
{
    t = fun(n-1,fp);  -- Call with n = 4, fp = 5.. The recursive 
                         function is called here and the return 
                         value needs to be checked only after all 
                         the functions return.

// First Call
    t = fun(n-1,fp);  -- Call with n = 3, fp = 5 

// Second call 
    t = fun(n-1,fp);  -- Call with n = 2, fp = 5   

// Third call 
    t = fun(n-1,fp);  -- Call with n = 1, fp = 5   

// Fourth call -- Here the If condition is valid, and the recursive function ends. 
                  We can now check the return values of all functions in reverse order.
    if(n <=1)
    {
        *fp = 1;
        return 1;
    }

// After Third call -- fp = 1, t=return of previous == 1
    f = t + *fp;
    *fp = t;          -- fp = 2
    return (f);       -- return 2

// After Second call
    f = t + *fp;      -- f = 4
    *fp = t;          -- fp = 4
    return (f);       -- return 4

 // After First call  -- t = 4, fp = 4
    f = t + *fp;      -- f = 8
    *fp = t;          -- fp = 8
    return (f);       -- return 8
```

Final Printed value is `8`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int fun(int,int *); // <- define function
    int main()
    {
     int x = 5; // variable x and its value is 5
    printf("%d,the value of fun is:",fun(5,&x)); //<- print value and function call with var x pointer edit
    return 0;
    }
    int fun(int n,int *fp)//<- define function
    {
      int t,f;//two var

      if(n <=1)//if n is small end function and return value 
       {
        *fp = 1;
        return 1;
       }
      t = fun(n-1,fp); // t any val 1 en recursive method start
      f = t + *fp;
      *fp = t;
      return (f);
     }

    one

    n = 5     x = 5

    part 1
    n=5 <= 1 ? -> false
    n-1 = 4    fp = x = 5
    call function fun(4,5)
    -------------
    Part 2
    n=4 <= 1 ? -> false
    n-1 = 3    fp = x = 5
    call function fun(3,5)
    --------------
    Part 3
    n=3 <= 1 ? -> false
    n-1 = 2    fp = x = 5
    call function fun(2,5)
    ---------------
    Part 4
    n=2 <= 1 ? -> false
    n-2 = 2    fp = x = 5
    call function fun(1,5)
    ---------------
    Part 5
    n=1 <= 1 ? -> true
    fp = x = 1
    return 1
    --------------
    ##############
    --------------
    return Part 4
    t = 1 
    f = t=1 + fp=x=1 = 2
    fp =x=t=1
    return (f=2);
    ---------------
    return Part 3
    t = f=2 
    f = t=2 + fp=x=1 = 3
    fp =x=t=2
    return (f=3);
    ---------------
    return Part 2
    t = f=2 
    f = t=2 + fp=x=2 = 4
    fp =x=t=2
    return (f=4);
    ---------------
    return Part 1
    t = f=4 
    f = t=3 + fp=x=4 = 8
    fp =x=t=4
    return (f=8);
    ---------------

    Exit:

    8,the value of fun i
```

s:

Good (y)